# Seekbar on popup window

Tags: android, popupwindow, seekbar

I have two seekbar on popup window, which works ok! My problem is that, Always when I return to a popup window, the seekbars is reset to 0, not at the positions where it was last set.

```
         SeekBar volbar1 = (SeekBar)popupView.findViewById(R.id.VolBar1);
         volbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(barChange);


         SeekBar volbar2 = (SeekBar)popupView.findViewById(R.id.VolBar2);
         volbar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(barChange);

         barChange = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
         {


            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {  }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {  }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) 
            {



                switch (seekBar.getId())
                {
                 case R.id.VolBar1:
                     snd.setVolume((float)progress/100.0f);

                     break;

                case R.id.VolBar2:
                     sndtwo.setVolume((float)progress/100.0f);

                    break;




                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the current progress you get from `onProgressChanged()`, which is a method of your OnSeekBarChangeListener. When you open the popup, initialize the SeekBar with `setProgress()`.

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity{

    int currentProgr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(...);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ...

                SeekBar volbar1 = (SeekBar)popupView.findViewById(R.id.bar);
                volbar1.setProgress(currentProgr);
                volbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                    ...

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                            boolean fromUser) {
                        currentProgr=progress;
                    }
                });

                ...

                popupWindow.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.b1), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

To save the progress when the device is rotated for example, you need to [save your instance state.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)
To save the progress across multiple sessions, you need to save it as a [preference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html).

Comment: Hi, do you mean like "setProgress(100);". I have try that but then it set seekbar to that "100" value, when i open popup window. Not where it was last set!

Comment: As I wrote, you get the current value from onProgressChanged(). Save it, and use that in setProgress(lastProgress);

Comment: I know what you mean, I just do not know how to save progress on mycode. Can you edit my code to show exactly how to do it ? Thanks :)

Comment: Finally got it to work, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @ Harry Silver. Hi, One more question, now that seekbars works as it should, I faced a new problem. Popupwindow with seekbars works well when using it on one or two activity. But when i implement it on all 8 activity, my app start crashing?